# How to determine size of art assets for Unity UI?

Tags: unity

Previously when I made games, I used ui assets from the asset store. Working with those assets was easy as the backgrounds were plain. However, I'm now working on a game where custom graphics are used for UI. So, I need to specify size of backgrounds,icons etc to the art team. I understand how aspect ratio works with regards to unity camera, but having trouble understanding the relation between camera size and Canvas. For example, for a camera size of 4.6, an image size of 517X920 will cover the whole screen in 9:16 aspect. However, the same image is considerably larger when used as UI image under the Canvas.
Can someone please help me understand how Canvas deals with image sizes?

Comment: Are you working with 2D or 3D?

Comment: Screenspace overlay. 2D

Comment: and UI Scale Mode of Canvas Scaler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. First I had to chose a screen size I'm designing for. I chose 768X1024. 
Gave artists this as reference, and they created all elements wrt this size. Next, in Unity, I set 768X1024 as reference resolution for Canvas. So, everything looked just like the artists had designed.